# Multidimensional array to string using implode

Tags: php, arrays

Alright so for some reason even with implode in place I am getting an error saying Array to string Conversion on this line

```
echo implode($weather['list'][0]['weather']);
```

> Notice: Array to string conversion in

Comment: could we please see a bit more of your code and what exactly you are trying? is it a 3 or 4 dimensional array?

Comment: Well that what I am getting from the openweather.org, its a 3D array.

Comment: even without the other code, i can tell that a multi-dimensional array is not going to work where `$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone'); $simple = implode($array);` does.  (can't imagine why we would want "lastnameemailphone" though)

Comment: This is what I get from the var dump (atleast 1 part of it, its kinda big but it doesnt expand bigger than this) http://pastebin.com/KteUqtqc

Comment: whats the content of weather ? what are you trying to obtain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this notice while trying to implode an array with inner dimensions:

```
$arrayWithInnerDimensions = [
    'first_dimension' => [
            'a',
            'b' => [1,2],
            'c',
        ]
    ];

echo implode($arrayWithInnerDimensions['first_dimension']); //notice

echo "\n\n";

$arrayWithoutInnerDimensions = [
    'first_dimension' => [
            'a',
            'b' => 'd',
            'c',
        ]
    ];

echo implode($arrayWithoutInnerDimensions['first_dimension']); //ok
```

Comment: I cant really modify the array as its sent from an outside source so I dont see what are you trying to tell me with this

Comment: I suppose You need something like that [implode multidimensional arrays](http://www.craiglotter.co.za/2010/04/09/php-implode-a-multi-dimensional-array/)